# Rowspan Images of Variable Height so Text is Always Evenly Spaced

Tags: css, html, dynamic-html

I am creating a display page for Photo Library. The page will have 4 photo attributes - File Name, Title, Date Taken, and Photographer Name, and also a preview thumbnail of the photo itself. I'm trying to achieve a consistent look, but unfortunately the images come in both landscape and portrait, so while the landscape images look consistent, the portrait images stretch out the distance between the attribute rows and therefor mess up the look.

My sample code is below, code on JSFiddle is located here - https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/37hkszbq/61/

HTML Code:

```html
<style>

.right-Padding{
   padding-right: 10px; 
}
img.resize {
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   max-height: 125px;
}

</style>
<table style='font-size:15px'>

<tr><td font-size='40px'>Image Name</td>
<td rowspan='5'><a href='" + href + "'><img class='resize' align='middle' src='https://p1.liveauctioneers.com/3283/129454/65998802_1_x.jpg?version=1540061833&format=pjpg&auto=webp&quality=50'></a></td></tr>
<tr><td width='50%' class="right-Padding">Image Title</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image Date Taken</td></tr>
<tr><td class="right-Padding">Image Taken By</td></tr>
<tr><td height='100%'></td></tr>

<tr><td font-size='40px'>Image Name</td>
<td rowspan='6'><a href='" + href + "'><img class='resize' align='middle' src='https://i.pinimg.com/474x/09/f6/83/09f683f4fde5a1e70c785ad1dedca58b--silver-belt-buckles-silver-belts.jpg'></a></td></tr>
<tr><td width='50%' class="right-Padding">Image Tile</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image Date Taken</td></tr>
<tr><td class="right-Padding">Image Taken By</td></tr>
<tr><td height='100%'></td></tr>

</table>
```

CSS Code:

```css
.right-Padding{
 padding-right: 10px; 
}
img.resize {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Search Google for 'css image max-width proportional'. The solution will be setting the max as you will fined, not relying on fixed width which will distort as you have found. Also, you want to consider separating the CSS from the HTML as it is easier to work with and more maintainable.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat - Your code is good except that it doesn't give me a consistent look.  On the first image (Kachina) the spacing between the text lines is much greater than in the second image (Kokepelli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your first image had a rowspan of 6, should be 4. Set a max-height for your images, I set it to 90px. Then remove the 25% width and height declarations from the `<td>` cells with the images. Finally, do you have to use tables? If you need a tabular layout, you really should be using CSS Grid.

```css
table{
   width:100%;
}
td{
   border:solid 1px #000;
}
img{
   max-height:90px;
   
}
```

```html
<table style='font-size:15px'>
  <tr>
    <td font-size='40px'>
      <a href='" + href + "'>Image Name</a>
    </td>
    <td rowspan='4'>
      <a href='" + href + "'>
        <img  align='middle' src='https://p1.liveauctioneers.com/3283/129454/65998802_1_x.jpg?version=1540061833&format=pjpg&auto=webp&quality=50'>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='50%' style='padding-right: 10px;'>Image Tile</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Image Date Taken</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='padding-right: 10px;'>Image Taken By</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td font-size='40px'>
      <a href='" + href + "'>Image Name</a>
    </td>
<td rowspan='6'><a href='" + href + "'><img  align='middle' src='https://i.pinimg.com/474x/09/f6/83/09f683f4fde5a1e70c785ad1dedca58b--silver-belt-buckles-silver-belts.jpg'></a></td></tr>
<tr><td width='50%' style='padding-right: 10px;'>Image Tile</td></tr>
<tr><td>Image Date Taken</td></tr>
<tr><td style='padding-right: 10px;'>Image Taken By</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Rowspan: Good catch!  I've changed the code a few times so previously I had six rows.  I find that the max height for images distorts images that are over 100 px.

Comment: @TomMolskow it won't distort them unless a width is explicitly set. `width:auto` will fix this.

Comment: I'll try that in the actual code, but here on the SO page it still seems to have bigger spaces on the page

Comment: There is no way to avoid that completely, a tall image is always going to be a tall image. You can remove the empty last row in each section and reduce the `max-height` to 90px (See me edits). It's either have the images be smaller than you want or have some of them be too tall for the rows.

Comment: OK, then the `max-height` isn't helping. If I employ `max-height` then the text looks good but images that are bigger get distorted.  If I don't use it, then the images look good but I still have the text problem.  Is there a way to dynamically set the `<td height='100%'>` of the last row based on image height?

Comment: @TomMolskow are you removing the width and height attributes from the cells with the images? See my demo, you can change the max-height to anything and the images don't get distorted.

Comment: I have now, but I think the problem is  can't normally have images that are set to height: auto and width: auto because some of them are so big, and I don't have any control over the image sizes that are uploaded - anyway you are right, your solution works - Thanks so Much!

Comment: @TomMolskow You're welcome. In CSS, if you set the `height` or `max-height` to a fixed height, just give the width a value of `auto` and the image will retain its aspect ratio.